# print [B byte array in frida js script

Tags: android, function-hooking

I'm learning frida and trying to hook a function that looks like:

```
`.method public final fn()[B`
```

It returns a byte array. Here's my code:

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var test = Java.use("com...");
    test.fn.overload().implementation = function () {
        var ret = this.fn();
        console.log("how to write here?");
        return ret;
    };
});
```

How to print the `ret` variable returned by the function? It's a *byte[]*. I tried `console.log` but it only prints a *[object]*, and `hexdump` complains *'expected a pointer'*. How can I print the array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/957652/2967945 should work for you. It might have a length field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var ret = this.fn();
var buffer = Java.array('byte', ret);
console.log(buffer.length);
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i){
    result+= (String.fromCharCode(buffer[i]));
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: But this only works for arrays with byte values that represent printable characters. Wouldn't it be better to just print the array in hex representation using something like `result+= (buffer[i] & 0xff).toString(16);`?

Answer (score 4):

Frida's java byte array element representation is signed number currently. Therefore, your byte array may contain negative number. We should edit accepted answer to reflect this:

```
var buffer = Java.array('byte', ret);
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i){
    result += (String.fromCharCode(buffer[i] & 0xff)); // here!!
}
console.log(result);
```

Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609447/9304999 and https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/289

Answer (score 2):

**One liner**
`console.log(Java.use("java.util.Arrays").toString(ret))`;

Answer (score 1):

## Dump byte-array as hex (Android only)

If you are using **Frida on Android** there is an alternative, using the Android built-in Apache commons codec Hex encoder. As far as I know all Android versions should include the class `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex`. Unfortunately the version available in Android does not directly output a String, hence you also have to use `java.lang.String` class:

```
function encodeHex(byteArray) {
    const HexClass = Java.use('org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex');
    const StringClass = Java.use('java.lang.String');
    const hexChars = HexClass.encodeHex(byteArray);
    return StringClass.$new(hexChars).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy:**

```
var stringClass = Java.use("java.lang.String");
var stringInstance = stringClass.$new(ret);
console.log('look = ' + stringInstance.toString())
```