# Read bytearray from retval on onLeave event

Tags: android, frida

I'm trying to get the return value of a android native function call using Frida but with no success:

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.getExportByName('lib.so', 'Token'), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
    },
    onLeave: function(retval) {
      console.log(retval);
    }
});
```

I know that the value is a bytearray but I can't find a way to read it from the native pointer.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What should I do the get the value from retval? I already tried to use cast, but it didn't work.

thanks

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17835/1413

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print \[B byte array in frida js script](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17835/print-b-byte-array-in-frida-js-script)

Comment: Found the problem: Need to to do this before creating the buffer array: `var b = Java.use('[B') var buffer = Java.cast(retval, b);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to cast to array buffer:

````
        var b = Java.use('[B')
        var buffer = Java.cast(retval, b);
        var result = Java.array('byte', buffer);

        var str_ = "";
        for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
            str_ += String.fromCharCode(result[i]);     

        }
        console.log("String: " + str_)

     }```
````